# AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied when trying to do copy_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have written a rake task that does an copy_to from one directory in a bucket to another directory within the same bucket. When I test it locally it works fine, but when I deploy it to an environment it returns AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied. I assume that it has something to do with the AWS credentials on the environment I am deploying too, I am also confident that the problem is to do with the copy_to as I accessed the bucket from the rails console and had no issues

my copy from statement is as follows

```
   creds = YAML::load_file(Rails.root.join("config", "s3.yml"))

   AWS.config(aws_access_key_id: creds[:access_key_id],
               aws_secret_access_key: creds[:secret_access_key])

s3.buckets['test-bucket'].objects['path to file'].copy_to('new_path')
```

Comment: Can you show us the code which initializes s3 variable?

Comment: credentials are just read from a YAML file. I checked in the console and they are being returned correctly

Comment: So when you do the same from console everything is ok?

Comment: What this command returns you back from server: *s3.buckets['test-bucket'].objects['path to file'].key* ?

Comment: it returns back the path to the object

Comment: I get Access denied from the console as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters to `AWS.config` are `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key`, without the `aws_` prefix.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS.html#config-class_method

Answer (score 1):

Found this because I also received Access Denied when calling copy_to(). While older SDK versions were happy to accept a pure key path as parameter to copy_to, newer versions require you to specify the bucket, too.

In my case

```
s3_bucket.object(old_key).copy_to(new_key)
```

did not work and produced a rather unhelpful "Access Denied" error with the v3 SDK. Instead, this works:

```
s3_bucket.object(old_key).copy_to( s3_bucket.object(new_key) )
```

or

```
s3_bucket.object(old_key).copy_to(bucket_name+'/'+new_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   s3.buckets['bucket-name'].objects['source-key'].copy_to('target-key', :bucket_name => 'target-bucket')
```

A simplified example using the aws-sdk gem:

```
 AWS.config(:access_key_id => '...', :secret_access_key => '...')
 s3 = AWS::S3.new
 s3.buckets['bucket-name'].objects['source-key'].copy_to('target-key')
```

Comment: hi Anil, unfortunately this does not help. I am pretty sure its something to do with security settings

Comment: you need to set a access policy to the buckets  before you perform some operations.